# Function addtobeamertemplate doesn't work from an sty file

Tags: beamer

I'm writting an .sty file to be used by several common presentations:

My sty file

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{multicol}

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]

%add logo to every page
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=south,yshift=5pt] at (current page text area.south) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=\linewidth]{images/logo};
\end{tikzpicture}}

%add logo to titlepage
\institute{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=5pt] at (current page text area.south) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=\linewidth]{images/logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

The problem is that the function addtobeamertemplate is not working, i.e., my logo ins't being added to every page.

Main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{Template}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}


\title{Your Title}
\author{You}
\date{date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Example}
\begin{frame}{Example}
slide example
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a style (STY) file or just a normal TEX file that you want to load via input? And does it work if you type your command directly into the document?

Comment: I created an sty file with all the common stuff (packages and rest). If i put the code addtobeamertemplate in my main file it works. But since it is going to be a common code for all presentations i wanted to put it in a common file.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. a `}` was missing in your `\addtobeamertemplate` call
2. `Frankfurt` theme defines its own frametitle template, so you have to first call the theme and then do your `\addtobeamertemplate`, otherwise your previous changes are simply overwritten.

---

Two non-problems:

1. You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{color}`, as beamer already provides this functionality
2. In my opinion, `\usepackage{multicol}` does not make any sense to use with beamer, as beamer provides it's own `columns` environment.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%\usepackage{multicol}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm}}

%add logo to every page
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=south,yshift=5pt] at (current page text area.south) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

%add logo to titlepage
\institute{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=5pt] at (current page text area.south) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

%\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\title{Your Title}
\author{You}
\date{date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Example}
\begin{frame}{Example}
slide example
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]